# Log integral approximation

Tags: number-theory

It it true that $\operatorname{li}(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{x}\dfrac{1}{\log(n)}+O(\log\log\log x)$?

Also, how close to $\operatorname{li}(x)$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{x}\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}}$?

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler-Maclaurin summation?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: If the hint leads you to an answer to your question, I encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.